# How to get Date List Between two dates on Android using with Java

Tags: java, android, date

I am working with Leave Application.
I need a list of all dates between two dates. But I can't do this.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post sample two dates. Then post the list you want to get based on those two dates.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. Please search.

Answer (score 1):

checkout, if this is helpfull to you:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class DateManager {

     public DateManager() {
     }

    public List<LocalDate> getLocalDateListBetween(LocalDate date1, LocalDate date2) {
         List<LocalDate> list = new LinkedList<>();
         //return empty list, if same days
         if(date1.isEqual(date2)) return list;
         //swap days if wrong order
         if(date1.isAfter(date2)) {
            LocalDate temp = date1;
            date1 = date2;
            date2 = temp;
         }
         list.add(date1);//remove this, if you don't want first Date to be in List
         while(!date1.isEqual(date2)) {
             date1 = date1.plusDays(1);
             list.add(date1);
         }
         return list;
     }
 }
```

call from anywhere like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //localdate: year-month-day
         LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("2021-05-05");
         LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("2021-05-10");

         DateManager manager = new DateManager();
         System.out.println(manager.getLocalDateListBetween(date1, date2));
    }
```